# JavaScript change timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, twitter

Hello I am using Twitter REST API to call the home_timeline for timelines.

But I found that the object it returned had the `created_at` with GMT+0 timezone, how can I adjust the timezone to the user's local timezone for example GMT+8?

Here is the original data with GMT+0 from Twitter API:

```
Wed May 04 16:23:13 +0000 2016
```

Comment: Date objects don't have a timezone, they are UTC. The *getHour*, getMinute*, etc. and *toSting* methods return values adjusted for the host timezone offset. You can present a timestamp in a particular timezone by adjusting the Date time value by the required offset.

Answer (score 0):

what's the expected output format?

you can try:

```
var d = new Date('Wed May 04 16:23:13 +0000 2016');
var localeTime = d.toLocaleString();
console.log(localeTime);
```

if you expect a specific output format, you can use http://momentjs.com/timezone/ , to change both the timezone and format

Answer (score 0):

I'm highly recommend to use [MomentJS timezone library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

Furthermore, I'm recommend not to use GMT+8 label for time shifting, and use, for example, "Asia/Shanghai" instead. I would save hours to debug for you.

So, code [barebone look like](https://tonicdev.com/maskim/moment-timezone-example):

```
let moment = require("moment-timezone");
moment("Wed May 04 16:23:13 +0000 2016").tz("Asia/Shanghai").format('YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss')
```

Output would be something like `"20160505 12:23:13"`.

Thanks!